# what is the jQuery / javascript context of a frame within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, frameset

Let me preface this with... I have referenced this question/answers and it seems to contain clues, but i'm still missing the whole picture

[Run JQuery in the context of another frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame)

Essentially, the structure of the index page is this

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="frames-wrap">
      <iframe id="this-iframe" src="location.php">

      </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

location.php then contains a frameset (ahem, not my idea...) that has two frames that are set up like so...

```
<frameset cols="350,*">
  <frame src="search.php" id="frame_search" name="search"/>
  <frame src="edit.php" id="frame_edit" name="edit" />
</frameset>
```

if i want to manipulate objects between the index page and these elements how would i go about this?

I keep thinking the context should be something similar to `window.parent.frames[0].document`... what else am i missing?

Comment: also referenced this, but i'm too new to post more than one link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page (shameless self-promotion as the question was originally asked by me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preface: You wont be able to access the iframes contents unless it originates from the same domain.

To select elements in your iframe you could use a jQuery call like this

```
element = $("#this_iframe").contents().find("#frame_search")
```

The key is to use the `contents()` function. See [Traversing/contents](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents)

Comment: ahh contents() is indeed awesome, i didn't realize the iframe support that provided... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think the link from technicolorenvy has the answer, but the selector has a lesser known  second parameter where you can set the context.

Something like this:

```
var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('myIframe');
iframeDoc = (iframeDoc.contentWindow) ? iframeDoc.contentWindow : (iframeDoc.contentDocument.document) ? iframeDoc.contentDocument.document : iframeDoc.contentDocument;


// From the parent window
$('p', iframeDoc).html('Hello from parent');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext

Answer (score 1):

Giving your frames ids that are valid JavaScript identifiers would help, then you could use constructs such as `window.top.this_iframe.frame_edit.document` as your context.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! however, this is bombing for me. the ids now have underscores rather than ndashes. if i use console.log to see what's happening "behind the scenes" it will return something if i log window.top.this_iframe.document OR if i log window.top.document.getElementById('this_iframe') so it appears that the frame_edit id is not being "seen". any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These were all helpful. I kept bombing when I was attempting to get past the iframe in the DOM. THis would appear to be from the fact i had code residing in the ready() method, but the frameset that was being called within the iframe was not loaded by the time that had $(document).ready() fired.

Thanks for all the great help and feedback!