# jQuery - Given an iFrame dialog in the same domain of the parent window, how to remove an item from the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that loads a fancybox iframe dialog. In that dialog an ajax call can be made that returns a JS response. I want that response in the iFrame to remove an element on the parent window. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(parent.document + ' #attachment-<%=@attachment.id%>').fadeOut('slow');
```

This isn't working. Suggestions? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run JQuery in the context of another frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame)

Comment: alert and you will see why it fails

    `alert(parent.document + ' #attachment-<%=@attachment.id%>');` You are adding an object plus a string so you get something wrong.

Comment: ok I tried that as, $('#attachment-<%=@attachment.id%>', window.parent.frames[0].document).fadeOut('slow'); and it doesn't error and has no effect.

Comment: If I alert I get [object, object] which means jquery can find it. But it doesn't remove or fade out. Is it a problem having jQuery in the parent window and iframe?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you need a "#" or "." after the "$("

So for example $("#myDiv") or $(".MyDiv"). I'm guessing that is your problem.

Comment: My guess would have been.

    $('#attachment-<%=@attachment.id%>'

Can you confirm that <%=@attachment.id%> is returning something?

Comment: Interesting, so when I click $('body', window.parent.frames[0].document).remove(); in the iframe, it removes the iframes body NOT the parents.