# Why does frames disable javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that have this structure.

```
<frameset>

    <frame name="MenuFrame"></frame>

    <frameset>
        <frame name="topFrame"></frame>
        <frame name="mainFrame"></frame>
    </frameset>

</frameset>
```

And in the frame "mainFrame" i need to access some components with javascript.

I can get access to the components when just running the mainFrame in a separate window. Javascript works when running it alone.

When running all the frames i cant do any javascript. What causes this problem?

Comment: If you can, do not use frame, please, thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html

Comment: What is the JavaScript code you are using to access the other frame? Seems like that would be good information to share!

Comment: Well its not my choice its an very old site that im working on.

Comment: @epascarello Im just using `$("#id")` to get the element to see if it is available.

Comment: Because frames are DIFFERENT pages and $("#id") lives in a different page. You need to reference the frame where the element lives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run JQuery in the context of another frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame)

Comment: Included the `<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>` in all the forms now. I can access the form that I want like this `$('frame').get(2)`.

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons, the browser won't allow you to script across frames that are served from different domains.

Answer (score 0):

But in HTML5 there is a method to archieve this. Google for javascript postMessage() if you want more on this subject. Here's a little example I found: [html5demos.com](http://html5demos.com/postmessage2)