# How to dynamically embed html into a frame tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch data using the jquery ajax library and I want to add the returned html data to a frame object (without setting the source attribute). The general idea is that I want to showcase the html content as a seperate document in a frame. I tried putting the data into a div but this had the effect of affecting the main document. Thanks!

The frame is:

```
    <frame id="test"> 
</frame>

$.ajax({ url : url })
.done(function(html) { document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html });
```

The problem seems to be that the getElementById function is return Null. This problem is resolved if I change the frame to a div.

Comment: Is the frame under the same host?

Comment: @Juan Mendes: Yes it is.

Comment: Then show the code you're using to set the frame's content, it should work

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to the context. I am simply unable to retrieve the frame object by id.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved! This article for surprisingly hard to find. Essentially, this is the code I used to solve this :

```
doc = document.getElementById('test').contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.writeln('<p> Hello! </p>')
doc.close();
```

The article is : http://softwareas.com/injecting-html-into-an-iframe