# Previous Next Buttons in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, location-href

I'm trying to make previous and next buttons for viewing this pdf converted to html. I thought I should jump to the next anchor since each page has it's own anchor written like this:

```
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#1" target="contents" >
```

However when I use `$(location).attr('pathname');`
I get "/ArduinoHtml.html" no matter what page I'm viewing, so I can't subtract and add 1 like I was thinking of doing. Below is where I got and the files I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".previous").click(function(){
        // Needed Code Help
    });
    $(".next").click(function(){
        // Needed Code Help
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Previous and Next Buttons</h2>
<a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the ArduinoHtml.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Arduino and LEGO Projects</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="pdftohtml 0.36"/>
<meta name="author" content="Jon Lazar"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="www.it-ebooks.info"/>
<meta name="date" content="2013-09-06T04:13:41+00:00"/>
<meta name="subject" content="IT eBooks"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<frameset cols="100,*">
<frame name="links" src="ArduinoHtml_ind.html"/>
<frame name="contents" src="ArduinoHtml-1.html"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

This is the ArduinoHtml_ind.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#outline" target="contents">Outline</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#1" target="contents" >Page 1</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#2" target="contents" >Page 2</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#3" target="contents" >Page 3</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#4" target="contents" >Page 4</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#5" target="contents" >Page 5</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#6" target="contents" >Page 6</a><br/>
<a href="ArduinoHtmls.html#7" target="contents" >Page 7</a><br/>
```

Below is an image of what opening ArduinoHtml.html looks like. I'm new to this so I'm trying to give all the information I can.

Thank you very much in advance.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fu9n.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href` instead:

```
$(".previous").click(function(){
    var nextPage = Number(window.location.href.split("")[window.location.href.length - 1]) - 1;
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split("").push(nextPage).join("");
});
$(".next").click(function(){
    var nextPage = Number(window.location.href.split("")[window.location.href.length - 1]) + 1;
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split("").push(nextPage).join("");
});
```

Looks complicated, but here's what it does:

```
var nextPage = window.location.href.split("")[window.location.href.length - 1] - 1;
```

This gets the current path (`window.location.href`), makes it an array `.split("")`, obtains the last character (the number) (`[window.location.href.length - 1]`) and subtracts 1 (`-1;`). Same follows for the `Next` button, except it's adding rather than subtracting.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split("").pop().push(nextPage).join("");
```

This makes the current URL (`window.location.href`) equal to the current URL (`window.location.href`), turns it into an array (`.split("")`), takes off the last character (the number) (`.pop()`), adds the new digit to the end (`.push(nextPage)`) and turns it back into a string (`.join("");`).

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the same page just keeps reloading. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I fixed the issue - I was using strings not numbers. Does it work now @DMOD?

Answer (score 0):

If the page is more static, you can do something like:

```
var pages = 7;
var currentPage = 0;
var pageUrl = "ArduinoHtmls.html";

$(function(){
  $(".previous").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(currentPage == 0){
      return false;
    }
    var prevUrl = pageUrl + "#";
    if(currentPage == 1){
      prevUrl + "outline";
    } else {
      prevUrl + (--currentPage).toString();
    }
    $("frame[name='contents']").attr("src", prevUrl);
  });
  $(".next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(currentPage == pages){
      return false;
    }
    var nextUrl = pageUrl + "#" + (++currentPage).toString();
    $("frame[name='contents']").attr("src", nextUrl);
  });
});
```

If the page is less static, you can still use a lot of this untested code. One minor difference:

```
var pages = $("a[target='contents']", window.frames[0].document).length;
```

I am suspicious that this code will not work right away. It's a little hard to understand the relationship of each of the pages as you have described it. I suspect you either want this code in the `ArduinoHtml.html`, yet I do not know where your buttons will reside since this page is only the frameset page and I suspect you will end up having to make a new frame to contain the HTML for your buttons.

If you decide to create a frame to contain the buttons, then the code is a little more complex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    var frames = window.parent.frames;
    var pages = $("a[target='contents']", frames[0].document).length;
    var currentPage = 0;
    var pageUrl = "ArduinoHtmls.html";
    var contentFrame = frames[1];

    $(".previous").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(currentPage == 0){
        return false;
      }
      var prevUrl = pageUrl + "#";
      if(currentPage == 1){
        prevUrl + "outline";
      } else {
        prevUrl + (--currentPage).toString();
      }
      contentFrame.location.href = prevUrl;
    });

    $(".next").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(currentPage == pages){
        return false;
      }
      var nextUrl = pageUrl + "#" + (++currentPage).toString();
      contentFrame.location.href = nextUrl;
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Previous and Next Buttons</h2>
  <a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So hopefully this helps answer your post yet I think it also opens a can of worms for you too.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame

Comment: I haven't had much luck either way. The second way you suggested gives can not find "/ArduinoHtmls.html#1" file because the actual file names are "/ArduinoHtml-1.html" I have too much of a headache right now to keep working on it at the moment but thank you for your help.

Comment: @DMOD initially that is the URL of the initial content, but as shown in your post, the links send the content to `ArduinoHtmls.html#outline`, `ArduinoHtmls.html#1`, etc. If it is saying `/ArduinoHtmls.html#1` does not exist, then maybe it needs to be `./ArduinoHtmls.html#1` instead.